# Node.js and mysql callbacks

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am new to node.js and callbacks. I have to search in 4 different tables depending on user's search configurations. There could be max 4 search queries. For example:

```
Table-1
    city
Table-2
    country
Table-3
    diet
Table-4 
    product
```

If user's configuration has city and country name then I need to search in Table-1 and Table-2. If I find any relevant information in any table, I need to return true and stop checking rest of the tables. If I cannot find relevant information in any table, I need to return false.

Mysql connector: "mysql": "^2.13.0"
Pseudo code:

```
function search(searchTerm, type, cb) {
    if (type=="city") {
        searchDB(searchTerm, "city", "fct", function (result) {
            if (result == true) cb(result)
        });
    }
    if (type=="country") {
        searchDB(searchTerm, "country", "fcy", function (result) {
            if (result == true) cb(result)
        });
    }
    if (type=="diet") {
        searchDB(searchTerm, "diet", "fdt", function (result) {
            if (result == true) cb(result)
        });
    }
    if (type=="product") {
        searchDB(searchTerm, "product", "fpt", function (result) {
            if (result == true) cb(result)
        });
    }
}

function searchDB(searchTerm, tableName, fieldName, cb) {
    var qryParams;

    var qry = 'SELECT * from ?? where ??=?';
    qryParams = [tableName, fieldName, searchTerm];

    qry = mysql.format(qry, qryParams);

    connection.query(qry, function (error, results, fields) {

        if (error) throw error;
        if (results == "") {
            return cb(false);
        } else {
            return cb(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How about a UNION instead of the JOIN?

Comment: The attitude of your question is pretty hilarious.  "call back hell" is likely poorly designed code you're writing, and not some requirement of the API.  "bad database schema" not allowing joins... yet you're somehow going to join in your code?  Sure, I suppose that's possible... why not just fix the database schema?  Are you sure you can't query with a join?  It's always better to let the database deal with your data when possible.  You'll get consistent data back that way.  Doing data manipulation on the application side is always asking for trouble.

Comment: In any case, you've provided no code at all, no example schema, no details about what you're trying to do, not even any mention of what MySQL connector you're using.  Not sure what you want us to do here.

Comment: Just use promises.

Comment: @Brad, Sorry about the wording. This is the term I found whenever I was looking for solution (edited question). Bad code? Is there a way to retrieve data from MySql without a call back? For database schema, it is out of my control. I am just trying to maintain a legacy code. I removed this part as well to seek for all the possible solutions. I haven't written the logic yet. I am analyzing the problem for now then I will implement the solution.

Comment: @Momi Again I ask... what MySQL connector are you using?  Where is your code where you're doing the query?

Comment: @Brad, I added the sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation you should use `Promise.race()` function. Not posting entire example here because a great and complete example is shown on MDN page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

```
Promise.race([p3, p4]).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // "three"
  // p3 is faster, so it resolves
}, function(reason) {
  // Not called
});
```

EDIT. Just realized you might not be using promises... Have a read about them, [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) are intended to fight the dreaded callback hell.

Comment: thanks! I will for sure look into it and get back to you.